# Simplify GeoJSON by retaining external boundaries (clustering)

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, cluster-tolerance

I created a website (http://www.cartescolaire.paris) that basically loads a GeoJSON and displays it on a map using Leaflet.

This geoJSON is pretty large (over 2 Mb), the loading time can be very long (it doesn't even load on IE 11). More importantly the resulting map is not very responsive when zooming / navigating.

There are around 110 zones/multipolygons (clicking on a point in the map highlights the zone it belongs to), each of them made from dozens of polygons.

However the only important information that I want to visualize is the external boundaries of each zone. Such a compressed geometry would be much more efficient performance-wise.

The complexity arises from the constraint that the zones shouldn't overlap. The final result should be disjoint clusters.

Any idea how I could do that?

@Stephen : The boundaries are pretty accurate and the orange sections are correctly located (they are actual buildings). I am prepared to do some manual processing if need-be ...

@Nathan : I didn't know turf.js and the buffering technique. I am a newbie in GIS space.
I've already tried Mapshaper, but although it is very efficient in simplifying each single polygon boundary, it doesn't help much in building the external boundaries for a group of polygons. Did I miss something ?

As you properly spotted, several zones have clusters outside the main area and that's one of the main issues.

I will also have a look at leaflet-beta to check if the rendering is better than in v0.7.7

My initial idea was to :

1. Run DBSCAN algo on each zone to identify clusters of polygons, fine-tuning  epsilon parameter visually
2. Run a concave Hull on each cluster to identify the boundaries
3. Finally, simplify the geometry

But I am sure there are GIS tools that can help instead of coding everything myself.

---

I finally followed Nathan's advice and buffered each geometry (+25 meters then -25 meters) then simplified the geometries up to 20%. 
The result is pretty acceptable and as expected the web page loads must faster and the navigation is fluid.

I used QGIS with a bit of Python scripting for buffering and mapshaper to simplify the geometries.

I haven't used turf.js for buffering since I noticed a bug in turf-buffer current version by which some features disappear after buffering. 
The issue has already been reported [here](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-buffer/issues/27).

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Do you require a fully automated solution, or would you be able to undertake some manual pre-processing of the data? How accurate are the boundaries - for example, are the orange sections which cross the street in [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/RZwDABM.png) mistakes, or are they correctly located?

Comment: You didn't miss anything in Mapshaper. I just meant to suggest that simplifying your existing polygons might reduce the file size enough that load time would no longer be a problem, making further processing unnecessary. Of course, processing the boundaries followed by simplification (as in your initial idea) would reduce the file size even further.

Answer (score 2):

A few answers but probably not the ones you're looking for:

1. Manually digitize the boundaries in desktop GIS
2. Try leaflet beta, it handles polygon rendering a little better.
3. Convert the geojson to topojson and/or use the geojson-vt plugin to create vector tiles.

See https://getbounds.com/blog/leaflet-and-geojson-tiles and also the original example found by viewing the source.

Answer (score 2):

A few other options, to add to those malcolm has already suggested:

- If the primary goal is just to reduce file size, you may want to try using http://mapshaper.org/ to simplify your geometry first. Depending on how much detail you need to retain, you may be able to reduce the size of your files quite a bit.
- You can remove many of the internal street lines by buffering each feature by roughly half the distance across the largest street, then contracting it (using a negative buffer) by the same amount. The result will still need to be cleaned up/simplified as there will be some overlap between polygons and probably also an *increase* in the total number of points (where previously straight lines become curved). Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/rj6qk8av/) applying this technique to a selection of your data using turf.js, though you could of course achieve the same effect just as easily with desktop GIS.
- If you are using ArcGIS with an advanced or ArcInfo license, it has an [Aggregate Polygons tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Aggregate_Polygons/00700000000s000000/) that appears to do what you want.
- Some other options using PostGIS etc. are described in [this GIS.SE post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24428/how-to-aggregate-detached-polygons).

I suspect that the desktop GIS options will also require some amount of pre- or post-cleaning of the data. For instance, I notice that several of the polygons actually have tiny slivers far outside the contiguous area, and those might need to be removed before applying a concave hull or running an aggregation routine.